# ssh.net c# runcommand issue

Tags: c#, ssh.net

I am using Renci.SshNet in c# on framework 3.5 and running a command on unix box like below.

```
        string host = "localhost";
        string user = "user";
        string pass = "1234";
        SshClient ssh = new SshClient(host, user, pass);


        using (var client = new SshClient(host, user, pass))
        {
            client.Connect();


            var terminal = client.RunCommand("/bin/run.sh");

            var output = terminal.Result;

            txtResult.Text = output;
            client.Disconnect();
        }
```

every thing works well, my question here is that "Is there a way that it should not wait for client.RunCommand to be finish" My prog doesn't need a output from unix and hence I don't want to wait for the RunCommand to finish. This command took 2 hours to execute so wanted to avoid that wait time on my application.

Comment: You want while the `RunCommand()` runs to be able to close your application or you want to prevent your application from freezing while running?

Comment: Why in mid 2014 are you limited to .NET 3.5?

Comment: I want my users to keep using the other areas of application instead of waiting for for 2 hrs to complete. I am limited at the moment to 3.5 but can upgrade to .net 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i assume SSH.NET doesn't expose a true asynchronous api, you can queue `RunCommand` on the threadpool:

```
public void ExecuteCommandOnThreadPool()
{
    string host = "localhost";
    string user = "user";
    string pass = "1234";

    Action runCommand = () => 
    { 
        SshClient client = new SshClient(host, user, pass);
        try 
        { 
             client.Connect();
             var terminal = client.RunCommand("/bin/run.sh");

             txtResult.Text = terminal.Result;
        } 
        finally 
        { 
             client.Disconnect();
             client.Dispose();
        } 
     };
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x => runCommand());
    }
}
```

Note if you use this inside WPF or WinForms then you will need to `txtResult.Text = terminal.Result` with `Dispatcher.Invoke` or `Control.Invoke`, respectively.

Comment: OP says 3.5; I don't believe async/await is available without some jiggery-pokery.

Comment: Right, didn't notice. Thanks.

Comment: it worked very well, any idea how to update the textbox value after operation completed... Dispatcher.Invoke is not available for web forms...

Comment: WebForms or WinForms?

Comment: WebForms it's a web application.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Your code in the finally block `client`  does not exist becasue you declared it inside of the `try` btw

Comment: @MethodMan Thanks, fixed.

Comment: I would have just moved this line outside the try `client = new SshClient(host, user, pass);` since you're only creating a new instance of `SshClient

Comment: @MethodMan Fair enough, didn't give it much thought :)

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
    public static string Command(string command)
    {
        var cmd = CurrentTunnel.CreateCommand(command);   //  very long list
        var asynch = cmd.BeginExecute(
            //delegate { if (Core.IsDeveloper) Console.WriteLine("Command executed: {0}", command); }, null
            );
        cmd.EndExecute(asynch);

        if (cmd.Error.HasValue())
        {
            switch (cmd.Error) {
                //case "warning: screen width 0 suboptimal.\n" => add "export COLUMNS=300;" to command 
                default: MessageBox.Show(cmd.Error); break;
            }
        }

        return cmd.Result;
    }
```