# Display complete SSH shell output including login message and prompt in C#

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, ssh.net

I'm trying to create a simple SSH client in C#. This is my code now:

```
using Renci.SshNet;

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AuthenticationMethod method = new PasswordAuthenticationMethod("pi", "raspberry");
    ConnectionInfo connection = new ConnectionInfo("192.168.91.134", "pi", method);
    SshClient client = new SshClient(connection);

    if (!client.IsConnected)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Not Connected...");
        client.Connect();
    }

    while (true)
    {
        string command = Console.ReadLine();
        SshCommand response = client.RunCommand(command);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Result);
    }

}
```

Problem:

- like this, it shows just the response of the command sent. I would like the entire output, also with the user and the current directory (like a classic SSH shell).
- if I want to launch the `sudo su command` giving the password it doesn't work...
  (in the future I want to add the output to a listbox and take the input from a texbox in a winForms app)

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25167826/ssh-net-c-sharp-runcommand-issue) post from 2014?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you want to implement an SSH terminal client (like PuTTY), you need to use SSH "shell" channel.

In SSH.NET, use `SshClient.CreateShell` or `SshClient.CreateShellStream`, not `SshClient.RunCommand`.

Answer (score 4):

This is my implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using Renci.SshNet;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SshClient sshClient = new SshClient("192.168.91.134", 22, "pi", "raspberry");

        sshClient.ConnectionInfo.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);
        sshClient.Connect();

        ShellStream shellStreamSSH = sshClient.CreateShellStream("vt-100", 80, 60, 800, 600, 65536);

        Thread thread = new Thread(() => recvSSHData(shellStreamSSH));

        thread.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            string command = Console.ReadLine();

            shellStreamSSH.Write(command + "\n");
            shellStreamSSH.Flush();
        }
    }

    public static void recvSSHData(ShellStream shellStreamSSH)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                if (shellStreamSSH != null && shellStreamSSH.DataAvailable)
                {
                    string strData = shellStreamSSH.Read();

                    Console.WriteLine(strData);
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I searched a long time to find out how to do this.  I couldn't find any documentation.  Every other example either showed how to Exec a single command, or focused on SFTP.  Thank you so much for posting this.  It worked perfectly for me.  I can now interact with a bourne shell on the remote computer.  I wanted a C# implementation to be able to send commands generated by the software as well as typing my own commands.